# Android: Best way to find a file in external storage 2020

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file

I am trying to find a specific file, that I already downloaded via `Downloadmanager`. I know that this file(s) are stored in `Enviroment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`. But what I don't know is how to get this specific file, because of the following reasons:

1. How do I make sure, to find my file on the fastest and safest way,
2. How do I find my file, when there are two versions of it (e.g `MyFile` and `MyFile1`),
3. How to make sure, that this works from API 21 up to API 30?,
4. Return null, when file not found,
5. Do I have to ask for permissions to find my file (do I even have to)?

This is my current approach:

### My Downloadmanager (saves files successfully in download directory)

```
private fun initDownload(uri: Uri, fileName: String) {
    val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

    val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
        .setTitle(fileName)
        .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
            "$fileName.pdf")

    downloadManager.enqueue(request)
}
```

### Find file (haven't tested it yet)

```
class FileValidator @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext val context: Context) {
    fun getFileOrNull(fileName: String): File? {
        // Have to create a generic regex to find every possible file that matches my fileName, don't know how
        val regex = fileName

        val downloadFolder = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
        val fileList = downloadFolder?.listFiles()

        if (fileList != null) {
            for (file in fileList) {
                return if(file.name == regex) {
                    file
                } else {
                    null
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

I appreciate every help, thank you

Comment: `I know that this file(s) are stored in Enviroment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` No. The file will be in a Downloads directory. There can be many of such directories. Yours is in getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS). No permissions needed. Works in all versions.

Comment: And you are trying to tell me with that?

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand you.

Comment: What are you trying to even tell me with your comment? I mean ok, I know where my files are stored, I already said that in my question? So what are you trying to tell me?

Comment: `if (new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName).exists())`

Comment: Thats creating a new File and does not get the old one. I think I solved my problem already, I will provide my answer later

Comment: No that does not create a new file. It does only check if a file with that name exists. Wich is exactly what you want i understood. Glad you appreciate my help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. I will check your answer as well.

Comment: @blackapps One question, what happens when the file does not exist? Does it return null or an Exception?

Comment: A boolean. Hence true if the file exists and false if not.